# google charts json date react

Tags: javascript, json, date, charts

I've been trying to use Google charts with react. It works well, but I've moved the data from a local file to a mongoDB, which gives me a date-issue. 
With my test-data I added a correct data-format in the google-charts using new Date(...). After moving the data, I'm getting the data from DB as JSON and this gives me a problem with the dates, that are just being printed as strings on my charts.

I've read on google's chart docs, that they automatically rebuild the date object from JSON-strings, if I keep the data in the following order 'Date(2015, 3, 3)'.

My data looks like this:

```
{ data: 
  [ [ 'Dato', 'Place1', 'Place2' ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-2)', 100, 0 ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-3)', 850, 0 ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-4)', 1125, 0 ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-5)', 0, 1900 ] ],
  path: 'Gennemsnitlig liggetid fordelt på kommuner' 
}
```

It's still being interpreted as Strings in the google chart. I've seen other examples, where they're using Rows and Columns. Don't know if that's my mistake. Here's an example from Stackoverflow:

```
 {"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(year, month)"},{"v":"2095"}]}],"cols":
[{"type":"datetime","label":"DTU"},{"type":"number","label":"COUNT"}]}
```

So, to sum it up. Everything works when using my testdata. The graph still works, when I'm getting data from DB. But the String dates I'm receiving from DB, isn't being recognized by the google charts as dates.

Hoping for some help or feedback

Regards

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read on google's chart docs, that they automatically rebuild the
>   date object from JSON-strings, if I keep the data in the following
>   order 'Date(2015, 3, 3)'.

Where have you seen this? Either way, the correct format is

```
[ new Date('2015-9-2'), 100, 0 ]
```

i.e a [**valid dateString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or

```
[ new Date(2015,9,2), 100, 0 ]
```

You can sanitize the data so you get the correct date values presented in the chart this way :

```
var testData = { data: 
  [ [ 'Dato', 'Place1', 'Place2' ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-2)', 100, 0 ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-3)', 850, 0 ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-4)', 1125, 0 ],
  [ 'Date(2015-9-5)', 0, 1900 ] ],
  path: 'Gennemsnitlig liggetid fordelt på kommuner' 
}    

for (var i=1;i<testData.data.length;i++) {
  testData.data[i][0] = new Date(testData.data[i][0].match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]);
}
```

The above just extract the dateString between `(..)` and replace the string in first column with a `new Date(..)`.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xxvymn7o/**

[image]

Comment: Your for loop in the client seems to do the trick. I'm now sending the the pure date ISO-string as JSON and doing your for loop in the client. Then it works. 
Thank you very much, David.